# How to find the best path for a roadmap in python?

Tags: python, optimization, maps, path-finding

So I have been interested in a project to help my dad with his business, or at least for my own whimsy. Basically, the job involves going to different fields spread throughout the county, and a lot of how we do it now is inefficient and leapfroggy. So I would try to create a system that will find an optimized path. I'm not asking someone to build any of this for me, I just need to know the right direction to look, for gathering information on how to do this. So we have a map of our county and or county, and luckily because we live in Nebraska all county's are just big grids. And we have a bunch of different fields we need to get too, for this task, there are 2 to 3 different teams who each drive there own truck( so 1 to 2 trucks). And in some cases, there is certain fields truck A has to check. So I just would like some help researching this, I would prefer to write this all in python. I know about pathfinding algorithms, but that's about it. So really here are my questions: How do I make, or use a roadmap in python? How can I institute a pathfinding algorithm to that map? How can I make 2 of those algorithms making there own path of the same length, ignoring certain fields? Any help is appreciated. Here is a low-quality picture of our field map https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L5GNoUrtzTxJvfKoS04wGO8EgkK8Ulue/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your problem sounds like a generalization of the vehicle routing problem. Google has some solvers with a Python API you can use to solve VRPs (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/). I do not know whether there are any libraries that allow you to consider fixed assignments of some vehicle to demand node.

Comment: Hey thank you for your insight! I will look into it!